# Know which month was 6 months ago and show name in spanish

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to postgres and I am trying to create a query to get which month was 6 months ago from today's date.
Also I want to show the month's name in spanish.

For instance: today's month is 'May' and six months ago was 'November' so I want to show the month' name in spanish 'Noviembre'.

This is how I am trying to do it but it only shows null rows:

```
    select 
( 
    case 
    when to_char(current_date-interval '6 Month','Month')='January' then 'Enero'
    when to_char(current_date-interval '6 Month','Month')='February' then 'Febrero'
    when to_char(current_date-interval '6 Month','Month')='March' then 'Marzo'
    when to_char(current_date-interval '6 Month','Month')='April' then 'Abril'  
    when to_char(current_date-interval '6 Month','Month')='May' then 'May'
    when to_char(current_date-interval '6 Month','Month')='June' then 'Junio'
    when to_char(current_date-interval '6 Month','Month')='July' then 'Junio'
    when to_char(current_date-interval '6 Month','Month')='August' then 'Agosto'
    when to_char(current_date-interval '6 Month','Month')='September' then 'Septiembre' 
    when to_char(current_date-interval '6 Month','Month')='October' then 'Octubre'
    when to_char(current_date-interval '6 Month','Month')='November' then 'Noviembre'
    when to_char(current_date-interval '6 Month','Month')='December' then 'Diciembre'
    end
) as "Hace 6 Meses"
from "recibopagoderechoslaborales";
```

Comment: There are two things to improve your original expression: `case extract(month from current_date - interval '6 month') when 1 then 'Enero' when 2 then 'Febrero' when 3 then 'Marzo' ... end`

Comment: @Abelisto this is the easiest way to do it. I am going to do it this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to adjust `lc_time` for your client:

```
so=# set lc_time = 'es_ES';
SET
so=# select to_char(now() - '6 month'::interval,'TMMonth');
  to_char
-----------
 Noviembre
(1 row)
```

not localised it looks:

```
so=# set lc_time to default ;
SET
so=# select to_char(now() - '6 month'::interval,'TMMonth');
 to_char
----------
 November
(1 row)
```

Comment: It failed on my OS for `set lc_time = 'jp_JP';` for example. Actually the localisation task is not so simple and it is definitely not the matter of the DBMS (lets say DBMS should to return the index of month like 3 or 7 or so, not its localized notation). (already upvoted for `TMMonth` never used such thing)